# Pivot and count conditions in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to use a dataframe like this(sorry for the formatting, I'm typing this on a phone):

```
'Date'                  'Color'    'Jar'
0   '05-10-2017'    'Red'       1
1   '05-10-2017'    'Green'      2
2   '05-10-2017'    'Blue'       1
3   '05-10-2017'    'Red'      2
4   '05-10-2017'    'Blue'       1
5   '05-11-2017'    'Red'      2
6   '05-11-2017'    'Green'       1
7   '05-11-2017'    'Red'      2
8   '05-11-2017'    'Green'       1
9   '05-11-2017'    'Blue'       1
10  '05-11-2017'    'Blue'      2
11  '05-11-2017'    'Red'      2
12  '05-11-2017'    'Blue'      2
13  '05-11-2017'    'Blue'       1
14  '05-12-2017'    'Green'      2
15  '05-12-2017'    'Blue'       1
16  '05-12-2017'    'Red'       1
17  '05-12-2017'    'Blue'      2
18  '05-12-2017'    'Blue'       2
```

and deriving one that looks like the one below with the columns filled in with count of instances per date.

```
Date.                     Jar 1 Red    Jar 2 Red   Jar 1 Green  Jar 2 Green Jar 1 Blue Jar 2 Blue
05-10-2017
05-11-2017
05-12-2017
```

I was trying to use groupby in order to accomplish this and was able to get the counts of each color for each day but I'm unsure of how to go about splitting the color columns by which Jar they came from.  I also read that query or loc might bet options for accomplishing this. Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First off, WOW on a phone....

Comment: I took a long lunch ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try this:

```
df_out = df.assign(count=1).pivot_table(index='Date',columns=['Jar','Color'], values='count',aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)

df_out.columns = df_out.columns.map('{0[0]} {0[1]}'.format)

df_out.add_prefix('Jar ')
```

Output:

```
            Jar 1 Blue  Jar 1 Green  Jar 1 Red  Jar 2 Blue  Jar 2 Green  \
Date                                                                      
05-10-2017           2            0          1           0            1   
05-11-2017           2            2          0           2            0   
05-12-2017           1            0          1           2            1   

            Jar 2 Red  
Date                   
05-10-2017          1  
05-11-2017          3  
05-12-2017          0
```

Comment: This worked perfect! Now to teach myself whats going on here. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**

*`pd.crosstab`*

```
df1

          Date  Color  Jar
0   05-10-2017    Red    1
1   05-10-2017  Green    2
2   05-10-2017   Blue    1
3   05-10-2017    Red    2
4   05-10-2017   Blue    1
5   05-11-2017    Red    2
6   05-11-2017  Green    1
7   05-11-2017    Red    2
8   05-11-2017  Green    1
9   05-11-2017   Blue    1
10  05-11-2017   Blue    2
11  05-11-2017    Red    2
12  05-11-2017   Blue    2
13  05-11-2017   Blue    1
14  05-12-2017  Green    2
15  05-12-2017   Blue    1
16  05-12-2017    Red    1
17  05-12-2017   Blue    2
18  05-12-2017   Blue    2

df1 = pd.crosstab(df2.Date, [df2.Jar, df2.Color])
df1.columns = df1.columns.map('{0[0]} {0[1]}'.format) # borrowed this line from https://stackoverflow.com/a/46102413/4909087
df1 = df1.add_prefix('Jar ')
df1

            Jar 1 Blue  Jar 1 Green  Jar 1 Red  Jar 2 Blue  Jar 2 Green  \
Date                                                                      
05-10-2017           2            0          1           0            1   
05-11-2017           2            2          0           2            0   
05-12-2017           1            0          1           2            1   

            Jar 2 Red  
Date                   
05-10-2017          1  
05-11-2017          3  
05-12-2017
```

---

**Option 2**

`pd.get_dummies` and `df.groupby`

```
df1 = df1.set_index('Date')
df1 = pd.get_dummies(df1.Jar.astype(str).str.cat(df1.Color, sep=' '))\
                               .add_prefix('Jar ').groupby(level=0).sum()
df1

            Jar 1 Blue  Jar 1 Green  Jar 1 Red  Jar 2 Blue  Jar 2 Green  \
Date                                                                      
05-10-2017           2            0          1           0            1   
05-11-2017           2            2          0           2            0   
05-12-2017           1            0          1           2            1   

            Jar 2 Red  
Date                   
05-10-2017          1  
05-11-2017          3  
05-12-2017          0
```

---

**Performance**

## Small

```
100 loops, best of 3: 13.4 ms per loop # pivot_table
100 loops, best of 3: 9.05 ms per loop # stacking, grouping, unstacking
100 loops, best of 3: 10.4 ms per loop # crosstab
100 loops, best of 3: 3.57 ms per loop # get_dummies
```

## Large (*`df * 10000`*)

```
10 loops, best of 3: 42.8 ms per loop # pivot_table
1 loop, best of 3: 913 ms per loop    # stacking, grouping, unstacking
10 loops, best of 3: 43.1 ms per loop # crosstab
1 loop, best of 3: 885 ms per loop    # get_dummies
```

What you want to use depends on your data.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can try this

```
df=df.set_index(['Date','Color']).stack().reset_index()
df['Columns']=df['level_2']+' '+df[0].astype(str)+' '+df['Color']
df.groupby(['Date','Columns']).size().unstack().fillna(0)

Out[239]: 
Columns     Jar 1 Blue  Jar 1 Green  Jar 1 Red  Jar 2 Blue  Jar 2 Green  \
Date                                                                      
05-10-2017           2            0          1           0            1   
05-11-2017           2            2          0           2            0   
05-12-2017           1            0          1           2            1   

            Jar 2 Red  
Date                   
05-10-2017          1  
05-11-2017          3  
05-12-2017          0
```

---

**EDIT: Same approach, simpler, faster version**

```
df['columns'] = 'Jar ' + df.Jar.astype(str) + ' ' + df.Color
df.groupby(['Date', 'columns']).Jar.count().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

This version should beat `get_dummies` approach (or perform the same).

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ `dummy`is the best:-)

Comment: Not for long... look at the large test!

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: faster version submitted as edit, for sport ;) (under review)

Comment: @FabienP It is faster than dummies by 0.3 ms. For the large test, it is 800ms, so not much of an improvement there. Nice one though.